# Deploying gevent in Django with mod_wsgi under Apache

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, gevent

It is working fine under Django's runserver with the monkey patch:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import gevent
  from gevent import monkey
  monkey.patch_all()
  execute_manager(settings)
```

However, in production we are using Apache with mod_wsgi, and a wsgi file. Putting the above in the WSGI file has no effect. It seem that when the wsgi file is called, it is not as `__main__`, but removing the `if` also does nothing.

I found `gevent.wsgi.WSGIHandler()` and tried to replace `django.core.handlers.wsgi` with it, but it requires `request` and `application` as parameters, which I don't have in my wsgi file.

This is what my wsgi file looks like:

```
import os,sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from gevent import wsgi
sys.path.append('/app/src')
sys.path.append('/app/src/webInterface')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'WebInterface.settings'

#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
application = wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that __name__ is not '__main__' in mod_wsgi. Even without the if(), where in the WSGI script file did you place the monkey patch call? You don't show that in what the WSGI script file looks like.

Overall, using gevent monkey patching in mod_wsgi is probably a bad idea anyway. This is because using gevent usually gives people a false sense of security that they no longer have to deal with thread locking because greenlets will to some degree order execution so for simple stuff it isn't needed. It is most definitely a bad idea to rely on that under mod_wsgi because all the request handler threads will still be real threads and not greenlets because the threads are created as external threads using Apache thread APIs. Thus very much still need to handle thread locking properly.

One last thing. You may want to add to your question what you are trying to achieve in doing this, because your attempts at replacing the application with the WSGIHandler from gevent make no sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it does not make sense? I thought that gevent's WSGIHandler() was a monkey-patched version of native WSGIHandler(). I guess that's not the case?

Comment: The WSGIHandler() in gevent has got nothing to do with Django. It looks to me like an internal per request helper for gevent's own WSGI server. It is not even a valid WSGI application so trying to use it as the application object in a WSGI script should yield a 500 error on every request.

Comment: OK. Would be nice if the documentation mentioned this :)

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton So is there any chance to use gevent in apache wsgi server with django framework. After full project completion, I came across this. Now not even time to change into any other resource. Can we do some tweaks to make it work.

Comment: No, you cannot replace normal threads in mod_wsgi with gevent. Will never happen. This is because the threads are actually created down at Apache level and can't be replaced. For most users gevent is a bad idea anyway. This is because most don't understand the problems that can arise from having even one bit of code which isn't greenlet aware and so blocks your whole application. They are not a magic solution and can just cause bigger problems. Use with care and only if you know you really need them.

Comment: ^^^^  bummer  ^^^^